# Redirecionar com htaccess sem alterar URL

Tags: htaccess, apache, url, redirecionamento, proxy

Tenho um sistema que roda no endereço `www.dominio1.com.br/sistema` e preciso que o usuário ao digitar `www.dominio2.com.br/sistema` seja direcionado para `www.dominio1.com.br` sem que a URL seja alterada.

Fiz um teste colocando um *.htaccess* na raiz de `dominio2`, o qual segue abaixo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio2\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dominio2\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^/?sistema/(.*) "http\:\/\/www\.dominio1\.com\.br\/sistema\/$1" [P]
```

O sistema direciona corretamente, mas altera a URL para `dominio1`.

O fato de eu ter especificado a pasta sistema é por os domínios são de empresas diferentes, hospedadas no mesmo servidor e compartilham o mesmo sistema. Então pra divulgar, cada uma quer usar o seu domínio na URL.

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Boa noite! , tive a mesma duvida sua e encontrei a resposta aqui : https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/469785-redirecionar-com-htaccess-sem-perder-a-url/
Espero que ajude!